# Prove that $A-B=A$ implies and implied by $A\cap B=\emptyset $

Tags: elementary-set-theory

My work

Let $x$ be any arbitrary element of $A-B$
$$A-B=\{x: x\in A,\; x\notin B\}$$
$$=\{x: x\in A,\;  x\in B'\}$$
$$=\{x:x\in A\cap B\}$$

How do I proceed further?

Comment: How did you get $x\in A\cap B$?

Comment: HINt: $A-B=A\cap B'$

Comment: Take A-B=A, now you need to prove that there is no common element between A and B. Assume the contrary and can try to get a contradiction?

Comment: what part of the statement do you want to show in your attempt?

Comment: After second step : $x \in A \text { and } x \notin B$.

Comment: $\{x: x\in A,\;  x\in B'\}=\{x:x\in A\cap B'\}$

Answer (score 2):

alternatively:

> ${\color{Red} {\text{to proof}}}$:  $A\cap B=\emptyset$:
>
> > 1. We can use [Symmetric Difference of Equal Sets](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Symmetric_Difference_of_Equal_Sets) and [$(A\setminus B)\cap B=\emptyset$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/250500/is-a-contradiction-enough-to-prove-a-set-equality-to-varnothing?noredirect=1&lq=1) in fact: $$ \begin{align} (A\cap B)\Delta \emptyset&= ((A \cap B) \setminus \emptyset) \cup (\emptyset \setminus (A \cap B)) \\ &=((A \cap B) \setminus \emptyset) \cup \emptyset \\ &=((A \cap B) \setminus \emptyset)\\ &=(A \cap B) \setminus ((A\setminus B)\cap B) \\ &=(A \cap B) \setminus (A\cap B) \text{ (because we have that } A \setminus B= A) \\ &=\emptyset \\ &{\color{Red} \Longrightarrow} A \cap B=\emptyset \end{align}$$
>
> ---
>
> > 2. We can use [$(A\setminus B)\cap B=\emptyset$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/250500/is-a-contradiction-enough-to-prove-a-set-equality-to-varnothing?noredirect=1&lq=1) and
> >        " $A \setminus B= A\cap C \to A\cap B\cap C=\emptyset$ " in fact: $$\begin{align}A \cap B\cap C &= (A\cap C) \cap B \\ &= (A \setminus B) \cap B \text{ (because we have that }A \setminus B= A \cap C)\\ &=\emptyset \\ &{\color{Red} \Longrightarrow}A\cap B=\emptyset \text{ (because we have that } C=A) \end{align}$$

Answer (score 1):

1. Let $A-B=A$.

Assume for the sake of contradiction that $x\in A \cap B$. Then, in particular, $x\in A=A-B$, so $x\notin B$, which is a contradiction with  $x\in A \cap B$.

2. Let $A\cap B=\emptyset$.

a) If $x\in A$ then, since $A\cap B=\emptyset$, $x\notin B$, so $x\in A-B$. Thus $A\subset A-B$.

b) If $x\in A-B$ then, by definition, $x\in A$, so $A-B\subset A$.

In conclusion, $ A-B=A$.

Answer (score 0):

Hints:

For the forward direction.

- To prove a set is empty, the typical approach is by contradiction.
- Assume for contradiction that $A\cap B\not=\emptyset$ and $A\setminus B=A$, so let $x\in A\cap B$ ($x$ exists because $A\cap B$ is not empty).
- Can you prove that $x\in A$, but $x\not\in A\setminus B$?  Does this give a contradiction?

For the backwards direction,

- Assume that $A\cap B=\emptyset$.
- Since $A\setminus B\subseteq A$, all you need to show is that if $x\in A$, then $x\in A\setminus B$.
- Since $x\in A$, $x\not\in B$ as $A\cap B=\emptyset$, so $x\in A\setminus B$.

You could also do the backwards direction using the contrapositive.

- Suppose that $A\setminus B\not=A$.
- Since $A\setminus B\subseteq A$, there is some $x\in A$ such that $x\not\in A\setminus B$.
- Prove that $x\in B$ and get that $A\cap B\not=\emptyset$.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**

$A\backslash B = A\backslash(A\cap B)$